# HTML Select dropdown Menu, Jquery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have had many JS problems all day as I am completely new to JS but I have the following HTML:

```
<div id = 'drop'>
    <select name = 'option'>
        <option value="form1">Opt1</option>
        <option value="form2">Opt2</option>
        <option value="form3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id = 'NewContent'>
   //I need different content here depending on selection
    <div id="form1" style="display:none"><div>Content of Formksldmkjlad1</div></div>
   <div id="form2"style="display:none">Content of Form2</div>
   <div id="form3"style="display:none">Content of Form3</div>
</div>
```

I have an onchange event as seen below in JS:

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
    $('#NewContent').children().hide();
   $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

I had an issue where all the divs were appearing on page load so I added in the following JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#NewContent').children().hide();
});
```

the issue I have now is that the user has to click in the menu box to another item and then back to the item that they want. For example the dropdown displays:

```
1.opt1
2.opt2
3.opt3
```

In order to see the contents of opt the user would firstly have to change the dropdown to opt2 or opt3 and then back to opt1 to see the contents.

^apologies if this doesn't make sense I will work on providing a visual of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To seed everything for the first time the page is displayed just add something in your document ready to display the first div.

`$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#NewContent').children().hide();
  $('#form1').show();
});`

or use

`$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#NewContent > div:not(:first-child)').hide();
});`

in your initial selector to hide everything but the first child div.  Then everything should line up for your change events.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger `change` event right after you bind it, in order the correct content div to be displayed if select box comes preselected with some value on page load:

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
    $('#NewContent').children().hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
})
.trigger('change');
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DjgA2/

Comment: This seems to make all of the divs appear - I must have made a mistake somewhere in my code I just can' see it